# VB.Net: appropriate synchronisation object for waiting, not protecting

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, synchronization, locking, semaphore

I have `BBController` instances (my custom objects), where some may need to wait for a few others to complete first (dependencies). I have decided to have each controller lock some synchronisation object at initialisation, lets call it a Padlock, and then unlock it when its done processing. When its unlocked, any controllers that depend (or were waiting for) on the aforementioned controller can then continue. So this is not about protecting a section of code by allowing one thread, but instead telling anything that that depends on an output to wait until that output is available.

I have experience with Semaphores in objective c, so I thought I could use those here by having each controller initialise its semaphore with a value of 0, and then when finished signal it with a value of infinite or max. While that would work, I'm sure there is a better locking object to make use of, since the value property of Semaphore is of no use here since as many BBControllers can continue when the semaphore is signalled. I am new to VB.Net

Comment: Is a mutex what you are after? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SSS a mutex is pretty much same as a semaphore isn't it? Besides being signalled by the same thread that locked it